# Jquery mentions jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-ui

I am trying to understand jquery mentions plugin  [jquery mentions](http://ivirabyan.github.io/jquery-mentions/)and i came across this section in the plugin. Can anyone explain what does this mean? What does the last return function does especially?
I want to close the autocomplete dropdown when the matched value has length less than 4

```
     search: function (value, event) {
        var match, pos;
        //&& value.length >= this.options.minChars
        if (!value) {
            //sel = window.getSelection();
            //node = sel.focusNode;
            value = this._value();
            pos = Selection.get(this.element).start;
            value = value.substring(0, pos);
            match = this.matcher.exec(value);
            if (!match || match[1].length <= this.options.minChars) {
                return '';
            }

            this.start = match.index;
            this.end = match.index + match[0].length;
            this.searchTerm = match[1];
            //this._setDropdownPosition(node);
        }
        return $.ui.autocomplete.prototype.search.call(this, this.searchTerm, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this as i found out that the searchterm was not reset the dropdown wasn't returned a null value. So i changed the search code like this.

```
 search: function (value, event) {
        var match, pos;
        //&& value.length >= this.options.minChars
        if (!value) {
            //sel = window.getSelection();
            //node = sel.focusNode;
            value = this._value();
            pos = Selection.get(this.element).start;
            value = value.substring(0, pos);
            match = this.matcher.exec(value);
            if (!match ) {

                return '';
            }


            this.start = match.index;
            this.end = match.index + match[0].length;
            this.searchTerm = match[1];
            if (match[1].length <= this.options.minChars) {//customization: to check minChars

                this.searchTerm = '';// customization: to clear autocomplete dropdown
            }
            this._setDropdownPosition($('.mentions')[0]);
        }
        return $.ui.autocomplete.prototype.search.call(this,this.searchTerm, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this plugin, new jQueryUI widgets are defined - `ui.editablecomplete` and `ui.areacomplete`. Both these widgets basically extend the regular `autocomplete` widget to support `<textarea>` elements and `contenteditable` elements.

Whenever you type anything to the inputs (`<input type="text">`, `<textarea>` etc) the search method is running. If it passes the all the `if` statements in the `search` method, it manipulates the data and calls the last return statement: `$.ui.autocomplete.prototype.search.call(this, this.searchTerm, event);` which basically tells the `autocomplete` widget to take over and continue all its actions as usual. This can be analogous to overriding in classical inheritance.

Anyways, if you'd like to open the autocomplete dropdown only for more than 4 characters, you need to change the `matcher` regular expression. By default, it's `/\B[@]([^@]{0,20})$/` which limits the length of the input from 0 to 20 characters. I did not see a way to change it through the API, so I guess you will need to change the code a little bit.

This function defines the `matcher`:

```
MentionsBase.prototype._getMatcher = function() {
    var allowedChars;
    allowedChars = '[^' + this.options.trigger + ']';
    return '\\B[' + this.options.trigger + '](' + allowedChars + '{0,20})';
};
```

You can change the `{0,20}` to `{4,20}` (or `{5,20}` if you want GT and not GTE).

An even better idea, would be to create a pull request to the plugin's author that exposes the match regular expression to the API, instead of changing the code.

Comment: Thanks but i solved this problem. :)
Now i am stuck with bringing the autocomplete dropdown to the cursor in the textarea. I googled and tried all the solutions but no luck yet.